# Swift: How do I nil an unknown object by reference/pointer?

Tags: swift, pointers, object, reference, null

I'm trying to figure out how to deinit/dealloc/nil an object that is being sent into a function, without knowing the objects type. The function `KillObject`'s purpose is to simply nil the object being sent in – and so it is the object that is being sent in from the outside that should nil.

```
public class MyClass
{
    init() { println("MyClass init") }
    deinit { println("MyClass deinit") }
    func sayHello() -> String { return "MyClass says Hello" }
}

var obj1:MyClass? = MyClass()
obj1?.sayHello()

public func KillObject(inout obj:AnyObject?)
{
    obj = nil
}

var any:AnyObject? = obj1 as AnyObject?
KillObject(&any)    // want `obj1`to be sent in
obj1   // is still an object, should be nil
any    // is nil, correct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```
public func KillObject<T>(inout obj:T?)
{
    obj = nil
}

KillObject(&obj1)
```

Comment: This works just fine in Playgrounds, so I'm assuming it will work in real code as well. Thx!

Comment: Yes, it will work in real code. It takes an optional of any Type (represented by the <T>) and sets it to nil.

Comment: Using this in real code I found something very wierd!
I’m using it like this in a block `[unowned self] () -> Void in
KillObject(&self.myObject)` Then nothing happens! But in the `KillObject function` if I add double lines of `obj = nil` or a `println("Kill object: \(obj)")"` before the `obj = nil` then it works…Very strange, is it because of the block?

Comment: unowned is used to prevent a strong reference cycle, and this Swift magic likely interferes with the block or closure being able to set the object to nil. It depends on what your purpose is but if it is simply to allow deallocation to take place, then the best thing is usually to allow Swift to handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what is here:

You have a pointer to `MyClass` with `obj1`. Then, you create another pointer to the same instance where `obj1` points to, and store that as `any`. Then, you set `any` to be nil, and it will be nil. But you didn't change `obj1`, it points to that `MyClass` instance that it was set to.

Answer (score 1):

The object Type must be conform to the NilLiteralConvertiable type

```
public func KillObject(inout obj:NilLiteralConvertible) {
   obj = nil
}

KillObject(&test)
```

Comment: Does not work in Playgrounds. The last line gives error: Cannot invoke *KillObject* with an argument list of type *(inout MyClass?)'

Comment: You are correct it dosen't sorry, the correct answer however is posted below by GoodbyeStackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

obj1 refers to an object of MyClass. obj1 is not an object in itself but a reference to an object in memory.

any, when assigned obj1 also refers to the same object of MyClass as referred by obj1.

When you assign nil to any it refers to nil, but obj1 still holds an reference to the original object which is still in memory. Assigning nil to any will not make the real object in memory magically go away.

As far as I know, objects are reference counted in Swift. So if there is still at least one variable referring to object it will not be de-allocated. In other words object will not be deallocated from memory till all of variables referring to are set to nil or goes out of scope.